# FileStream CopyTo different extension

Tags: pdf, filestream, xlsx

Is it possible to convert xlsx to Pdf like that?

```
   FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Import.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
   FileStream targetStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Import.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
   sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are just copying the file to a new name. The actual content of the file will be exactly the same. No conversion is being performed.

Comment: Can i use Stream and convert to Pdf from excel?

Comment: If you actually do the conversion yes. pdf and excel files are two completely different file-types, and thus the content of the two files are very different. So you will need to understand both how a pdf file and an excel file are structured, and convert from one structure to another. This is in no way a simple task, and requires a throughout understanding of the file-types. Your are probably much better of finding a library which can create a pdf file from an excel file, that you can use, if one such exists.